# How to assign values for i, j in a certain range within a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix of random size (size input by user), where I want to assign values of 1, 2 and 3 to specific parts, the part giving trouble is where 2 will be assigned. The matrix should look like this...

1 1 1 1 1...1 (all rows and columns above this are ones, this I can do)

2 2 2 2 2...2

3 2 2 2 2...2

3 3 2 2 2...2

3 3 3 2 2...2

3 3 3 3 2...2

3 3 3 3 3...2

3 3 3 3 3...3

Assuming the 2's start at (i4,j0), and continue starting diagonally in (i5,j1), (i6, j2) , etc. I would like to know how I can make that in python.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that accomplishes this.

```
size = int(input("size? "))
i = int(input("i? "))
j = int(input("j? "))

for i_ in range(size):
    row = []
    for j_ in range(size):
        if i_ >= i and j_ >= j:
            row.append("2")
        elif i_ < i:
            row.append("1")
        else:
            row.append("3")

    print " ".join(row)
    if i_ >= i:
        j += 1
```

Run:

```
size? 10
i? 4
j? 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2
```